# Is this valid C++ to initialize a 2D dynamic array?

Tags: c++

This is in my teachers code, and it works for me using the GNU compiler, and for my teacher who is on a Mac, but for other classmates using Visual Studio, it throws a lot of errors. I'm thinking that with dynamic memory, you can't initialize something like this, or rather the C++ standard doesn't say you have to be able to. Am I correct in that?

```
store = new char*[rows];        
store[0] = new char[6]{'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'};
store[1] = new char[6]{'1', 'e', '1', '0', '0', '1'};
store[2] = new char[6]{'1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'};
store[3] = new char[6]{'1', '0', '0', 'm', '1', '1'};
store[4] = new char[6]{'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'};
```

Comment: It's only valid in C++11.

Comment: In which I believe you can write it more concisely and directly.

Comment: By the way, this compiles in VS2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a valid list initialization. However for example MS VC++ 2010 does not support it, 
Not all compilers support all features of the C++ 2011.

Comment: Didn't realize that was a C++11 feature. That's why I didn't know it was valid syntax.